# regex how to exclude specific characters or string anywhere

Tags: regex

```
the
cat
sat
on
the
mat
```

assuming those are different entries. what would the regex expression be to exclude a specific character, in this case "a", from anywhere at all in the thing you were searching for?

so the hits you would get back are "the, on, the"

---

or if it was a word as in

```
I like chocolate
bananas
chocolate cake
```

I would like only "bananas" to show a hit by excluding the word "chocolate" anywhere

Comment: sorry for formatting. stackoverflow has gotten rid of where i started each new word / string as paragraph. not my fault.

Comment: hey patrick, how did you do that? thanks

Comment: Its called "code blocks"  . put an empty line before code and indent by 4 spaces OR select all and click the **{}** button - adding an empty line between things often helps too

Comment: @youknownothingjonsnow: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: the first one you could do by `^[^a]+$` and multiline flag, the latter is trickier - depends on the language used - regex syntax has _flavours_ (js, c#, php, ...) - best go over to one of theonline regex-testers - I use regexr.com but there are lots to experiment with - google em

Comment: Patrick, your first answer to my first one, am I to understand it in natural language as "all entries that starts and ends without any requirement but without any multiples of a in the middle"?

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: hi Jan. I don't know. I am on a 1 year conversion degree for computer science and we have been introduced to regex without reference to any specific programming languages.

Comment: You should mention this or use a tag like [tag:language-agnostic]. Unfortunately, the answers you have received so far are specific to a group of regex dialects which is far removed from the computer science concept of regular languages. You might want to accept the duplicate I proposed just to buy time to ask a properly-scoped question before more enthusiastic newbies rush in with virtually identical answers.

Comment: (... Though [stevendesu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word#comment9209422_406230) on that question is basically the answer for traditional / computer-science-y regular expressions.)

Answer (score 20):

What you need is a negative lookahead for blacklisted word or character.

Following regex does what you are expecting.

**Regex:** `^(?!.*a).*$`

**Explanation:**

`(?!.*a)` let's you lookahead and discard matching if blacklisted character is present anywhere in the string.

`.*` simply matches whole string from beginning to end if blacklisted character is not present.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uzlIJA/1/)**</kbd>

---

For blacklisting a word you will have to modify and mention word in negative lookahead assertion.

**Regex:** `^(?!.*chocolate).*$`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uzlIJA/2/)**</kbd>

This will also discard match if `chocolate` is a part of string like *blackchocolate* *hotchocolate* etc.

---

Strict matching of word by adding word boundaries.

**Regex:** `^(?!.*\bchocolate\b).*$`

By adding `\b` on both ends it will strictly lookahead for `chocolate` and discard match if present.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uzlIJA/3/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

Your question is a bit vaguely phrased, in the end you'll have a couple of choices.

#### The first regex-solution (disallow characters in a word):

```
\b(?:(?!a)\w)+\b
# word boundary, neg. lookahead, disallowing "a",
# afterwards match as many word characters as possible
# in the end another word boundary
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/azicPj/1/).

---

#### The second regex-solution (disallow a complete word):

```
^(?!.*chocolate).+
# match the start of the line, additionally a neg. lookahead looking down the line
```

See [**another demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/azicPj/2/).

---

#### Programmatically:

Assuming `Python`, transferable to other languages as well:

```
sentence = "the cat sat on the mat"
words_without_a = [word for word in sentence.split() if "a" not in word]
print(words_without_a)
# ['the', 'on', 'the']
```

Comment: thank you! may I ask what the purpose of the ?: is? in the first example, adding it or removing it will still return the same 3 hits. but it changes the colour of captured groups.

Comment: @youknownothingjonsnow: `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, meaning it has the functionality of a group but does not capture anything separately.

Comment: @youknownothingjonsnow: If an answer helped you, please consider upvoting/accepting it (green tick on the left).