# watch files in folder changed using regEx

Tags: javascript, chokidar

i want watch, changes in the folders:

- test/index.js
- te3st/index.js

but not changes in

- te2st/index.js   not any te**NUMBER**st/index.js

i using chokidar and got inspiration from here: [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/47)

with `ignored: ignored: /^.*\b(?:(?!te2st\/index\.js)\w)+\b$/` its possible to use regEx, but my regEx did not work like expected ( [regex how to exclude specific characters or string anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139727/regex-how-to-exclude-specific-characters-or-string-anywhere) ).

this regex working here :
https://regex101.com/r/XnKYcf/1/

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
var watcher = chokidar.watch('/home/replays/0.0.24/t*t/index.js',
{ignored: /^.*\b(?:(?!te2st\/index\.js)\w)+\b$/, persistent: true});
watcher
  .on('add', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been added  ');})
  .on('change', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been changed  ');})
  .on('unlink', function(path) {console.log('File', path, 'has been removed  ');})
  .on('error', function(error) {console.error('Error happened', error);})
```

that is the ad negativo definition that does not yet work properly here. Allowing via regex would be much more practical and easier to read. is this possible?

Comment: workaround for the moment: `crontab -e` `*/2 * * * * php ~/doIt.php` with reads complete folder filtered by regEx

Answer (score 0):

this Answer not use the ignore Attribute really. It allows almost anything at first and then filters later. maybe it's easier to read as a solution with the ignore attribute, i haven't been able to implement it with that.

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');

var watcher = chokidar.watch('/home/x/0.24/t*t/index.js',{ignored: /$^/, persistent: true}); // /$^/ is match nothing

watcher
  .on('add', function(path) {
      if(path.match(/te(|3)st\/index\.js/)){
        console.log('File', path, 'te(||3)st found :) ');
      }
      
})
```

output of `$ node /home/x/0.0.24/file-watcher.js`:

```
File /home/x/0.0.24/te3st/index.js te(||3)st found :) 
File /home/x/test/index.js te(||3)st found :)
```