# Python regex does not match string as intended for some reason

Tags: python, regex

I have the content of an English dictionary at hand and I want to find the definition for a specific example sentence.

For example, I want to find the definition for "example sentence 2b". In my opinion, the code may look lile this:

```
re.search(r'\d\. ([^\n]*?)\n(?!.*\d\. ).*?example sentence 2b', content, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Here, the "content" is as follows:

```
1. definition1
example sentence 1a
example sentence 1b
2. definition2
example sentence 2a
example sentence 2b
3. definition3
example sentence 3a
example sentence 3b
```

Live test here - https://regex101.com/r/UOz6DA/1/

As you can see in the live test, I didn't get desired match - "definition2". I really don't know why.

PS: I used `(?!.*\d\. ).*` based on this post - [regex how to exclude specific characters or string anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139727/regex-how-to-exclude-specific-characters-or-string-anywhere)

Comment: By default, [dot '.' doesn't match newline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), hence `'.*?'` won't match the newline before *"example sentence 2b"*. Either use `re.DOTALL` flag, or put explicit `\n`'s in your regex wherever newlines can occur. There are many existing Q&A on SO about this.

Comment: @smci But I did use this flag, which is indicated by the "s" to the right of the regex on regex101.com. I have got my answer down below, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following pattern *without* the `re.DOTALL` flag:

```
^\d+\. (.*)(?:\n(?!\d+\. ).*)*\nexample sentence 2b
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkdFFU/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^` - Beginning of line.
- `\d+\.`  - Match one or more digits, then a dot, and a space character.
- `(.*)` - Match zero or more characters and capture them in group 1.
- `(?:` - Beginning of a non-capturing group.

  - `\n(?!\d+\. )` - Match a line-break that is not followed by a "definition line".
  - `.*` - Match zero or more characters.
- `)` - Close the non-capturing group.
- `*?` - Match the previous group between zero and unlimited times (lazy).
- `\nexample sentence 2b` - Match a linebreak character followed by the target sentence.

Comment: It only works for the second example sentence. For example, for "example sentence 2a", it  won't work anymore. That's the reason I find it necessary to use the "s" flag (re.DOTALL).

Comment: @wbzy00 `re.DOTALL` is still irrelevant. If you need to search for any example sentence (not necessarily the second one), then you could just add a `*` or a `*?` after the non-capturing group. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/EkdFFU/1).

Comment: Thank you! You are a hero. After putting so much effort into this problem recently, I finally find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `\n` character to match break line.
[image]

Comment: It only works for the second example sentence. For example, for "example sentence 2a", it won't work anymore. That's the reason I find it necessary to use the "s" flag (re.DOTALL).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't match is due to the existence of "3. ", even though this substring is after "example sentence 2b".

For a simpler example, if you use the "s" flag in this [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/uzlIJA/2/), the second line won't match any more because of the "chocolate" substring in the third line.